# Trouble with Python choice text game (if-then statement not working right)

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make a very simple game in Python 3.2.3 where I input a string character from a choice of options I have created and get a single result back.  After I get the results, it will will either loop back to the main menu function to make another choice or one option will end the program.

When I created this game, I was able to make a choice pop up when I typed it in but it always shows the first two options and not the one I input.

My choice results are a mixture of addition operators and print text. I don't know if this helps but I will paste the code below.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think it's my if-then-else statement since no matter what I move around in that function it always shows the same output.  But any tips would be helpful.

---

### Edit:

It may be best if I put in the entire code since I am now getting the

> NameError: global name 'xString' is not defined

Also: the set_sword(), set_rock() are all set as functions as well. They should be called when the user types "sword" and it should call the get_sword function (which it does but then it ALSO calls the set_magic() function.

Here is the edited code:

```
# ADDITIONAL DETAILS

# This code calculates the damage you would do if you were a heroic knight that is attacking an evil dragon.
# You have 6 options available in the main menu: Attack with your sword, attack with magic, block with your shield, Throw a rock at it, Run away, and Quit fight (or exit).
# The calculations involve subtracting the attack damage numbers against the dragons HP (or Health Points). For example, if your attack with sword number subtracts the dragons HP number and reaches 0: the dragon will be defeated and the game is “won’.
# When the game is won the game is reset back to the main menu (in this case the main menu are the fighting options.)
# I hope you find this particular project entry unique and fun!
# Main menu function. It should present the options available to input, allow the input of the listed options and be looped until the user uses the quit command.
def set_main():
        sword = set_sword()
        magic = set_magic()
        block = set_block()
        rock = set_rock()
        run = set_run()
        done = set_finish()
        print("Main Menu: ")
        print("Only one of your attacks can lower his HP to zero! What will you do?! ")
        print("Type “sword” to use a sword attack with an attack power of 60! ")
        print("Type “magic” to use a magic attack with an attack power of 80!")
        print("Type “block” to block with your shield with an attack power of 70! ")
        print("Type “rock” to throw a rock! with an attack power of ??? ")
        print("Type “run” to RUN AWAY DUDE! It has an attack power of only 1 though. ")
        print("Type “done” to finish the game and program. ")

# sword attack function that should be called if the input is "sword"
def set_sword():
        sword = str(xString)
        sword = 60
        dragon = 100
        print('The sum of ', sword, ' and ', dragon, ' is ', sword-dragon, ' Attack power! ', sep='')
        print("Your Super Special Overlasting Justice Power Sword attack did little damage!")
        print("The dragon grabs you and eats you whole! Gross.")
        print("Try Again!")
        return set_sword

# magic attack function that should be called if the input is "magic"
def set_magic():
        magic = str(xString)
        magic = 80
        dragon = 100
        print('The sum of ', magic, ' and ', dragon, ' is ', magic-dragon, ' Attack power! ', sep='')
        print("Your magic attack is too weak!")
        print("The dragon uses it's mighty feet and stomps on you!")
        print("So yeah, you're dead. Try again!")
        return set_magic

# blocking attack function that should be called if the input is "block"
def set_block():
        block = str(xString)
        block = 100
        dragon = 100
        print('The sum of ', block, ' and ', dragon, ' is ', block-dragon, ' Attack power! ', sep='')
        print("You blocked the dragon's attack perfectly!")
        print("Both you and the dragon are exhasuted and decide to fight another day!")
        print("So uh...Try again tomorrow?")
        return set_block

# rock throw attack function that should be called if the input is "rock"
def set_rock():
        rock = str(xString)
        rock = 150
        dragon = 100
        print('The sum of ', rock, ' and ', dragon, ' is ', rock-dragon, ' Attack power! ', sep='')
        print("In complete desperation you find a rock next to you and throw it at the dragon!")
        print("The rock hits the drgon square in the eye! It roars in pain!")
        print("The dragon then begins to cry and it doesn't like things hitting his eye.")
        print("The dragon then flies away from the castle in fear!")
        print("So..YOU DID IT! Congratulations! Try one of the other options!")
        return set_rock

# run command function that should be called if input is "run"
def set_run():
        run = str(xString)
        run = 150
        dragon = 100
        print('The sum of ', run, ' and ', dragon, ' is ', run-dragon, ' Attack power! ', sep='')
        print("You decide that saving the world isn't worth it and you run!")
        print("You decide to retire and leave a peaceful life. You find a nice partner, fall in love, and have children.")
        print("several years later the dragon storms into your village and wipes out everything!")
        print("Including you...")
        print("Was your time of peace worth it? Find out by trying again!")
        return set_run

# quit function that should quit the program if the user inputs "done"
def set_finish():
        print("Game over! Thanks for playing!")
        quit
        return set_finish

# default introduction print should explain the game and pretends an ending input.
print("The hero arrives in the dark castle and is welcomed by a large and evil dragon! You are that hero and must defeat the dragon to save the princess!")
print("The Dragon has 100 HP! ")
xString = str(input("What attack will you do?! (Type the attack name to pick an attack) :"))
if xString == "sword":
        print(set_sword())
elif xString == "magic":
        print(set_magic())
elif xString == "block":
        print(set_block())
elif xString == "rock":
        print(set_rock())
elif xString == "run":
        print(set_run())
elif xString == "done":
        print(set_finish())
else:
        print("Pick an option please.")
        quit
print(set_main())
print("Hope you had fun!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some problems, not the least of which is that you're comparing variables and strings.  Quotation marks count.  And I don't think you are still understanding DaoWen.  Neither of your assignment statements after your input statement need to be there:

```
xString = input("What attack will you do?! (Type the attack name to pick an attack) :")
# xString = 0
# xString = str(xString)
```

If you want to assure that your input is a string, do this:

```
xString = str(input("What attack will you do?! (Type the attack name to pick an attack) :"))
# xString = 0
# xString = str(xString)
```

And in your if...elif, you define variables when you don't have to.

```
# sword = set_sword()
# magic = set_magic()
# block = set_block()
# rock = set_rock()
# run = set_run()
# done = set_finish()

if xString == "sword":
        xString = 60 # I hope you know why you changed the value of xString
        print(set_sword())

elif xString == "magic":
        print(set_magic())

elif xString == "block":
        print(set_block())

elif xString == "rock":
        print(set_rock())

elif xString == "run":
        print(set_run())

elif xString == "done":
        print(set_finish())

else:
        print("Pick an option please.")
        quit
```

Comment: Yeah, as you can tell I'm new at this. And I changed the input but now when I try and run the program is says the colon I put after " if xString == "sword": " is the wrong syntax.  *sigh * I am getting stressed out. I've been working on this for almost 5 hours straight now. I do not like coding. :(

Comment: Well, with how your code is up top now, I don't even know if I can put it in IDLE to see what you're getting.

Comment: Sorry. Let me check if there is an option to attach files in the edit option.

Comment: Ok I edited my post. the stuff in bold are comments and the functions are above the grey boxes. if more editing is needed please let me know

Comment: Take your entire code, paste it into notepad, and then add four spaces in front of every line.  Copy that and paste that into your message and that's what the code will actually look like.

Comment: I did and re-pasted. It still doesn't look good...Maybe I should just delete the comments. I thought they would help.

Comment: I cannot run the code accurately on my machine the way you have it pasted.  Basically, the error you said you got should not have come from the code as I suggested you change it.  But at any rate, I think your original question is answered and the problems coming from the change in code might better be a brand new question.

Comment: Ah ok. Then thanks all. I'll paste another question when I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
xString = input("What attack will you do?! (Type the attack name to pick an attack) :")
xString = 0
xString = str(xString)
```

The value of `xString` after executing those 3 statements will *always* be `'0'`. I don't understand why you have the 2nd and 3rd assignments—you should probably just delete those.

***Edit:***

```
# This line reads the user input, which is probably what you want.
xString = input("What attack will you do?! (Type the attack name to pick an attack) :")
# This line throws away the user input in xString by assigning 0 instead
xString = 0
# Since xString = 0, this is the same as xString = str(0), which returns '0'
xString = str(xString)
```

***Update:***

I was assuming before that `sword = set_sword()` was returning a string, but now that you've posted your full code it looks like it's returning a function handle. You should follow James's suggestions so that you're comparing the input to strings rather than functions. There are still a lot of other issues with the code (e.g. what are you doing with `quit`?), so you'll still have some other issues to work out.

Comment: I want to have 5 options, though. Should I not use xString at all then? But I need an input that has 5 options with 5 actions associated with them.

Comment: See my edit above. I wasn't saying you should get rid of xString, I'm just saying you should get rid of the 2 extra assignments that overwrite the user input you had stored in xString.

Comment: Ah I see. I have gotten rid of xString but keeping sString = str(xString). When I run it though it infinitely loops. >_< ill check on how to stop that.

Comment: Gah, I stopped the infinite loop but now it says the xString isn't defined. I edited my post with the full code but yeah it looks all messy. If it's too much I will try and edit it again.